How fast to play Rachmaninoff’s Études-Tableaux, Op. 33 No. 5 in G minor?
According to wikipedia moderato is around 108-120 BPM. Does the time signature of cut time (2 beats per bar) here mean that there should be 120 half notes per minute (240 quarter notes per minute seems extremely fast for this piece). Actually, I think 60 quarter notes per minute feels good, but 120 is hardly playable (and 240 quarter notes per minute is impossible, for me at least, to achieve).


A glib answer, but: play all pieces no faster than 1) you can do well, and 2) "sounds good" to you. More seriously: "Moderato" just means "moderate." The 16th notes mean that this piece will "feel faster" than a piece without them. Listen to a bunch of recordings and see what's common.

Echoing @AndyBonner's comment: listen to recordings. :)

idem @AndyBonner and Paul Garrett, see my answer.

In the two editions I found in IMSLP, the Muzgiz 1948 edition (where it is numbered 8) and the Muzgiz 1970 edition (where it is numbered 7), the time signature is C or 4/4.  And when I checked these 3 performances, Vladimir Ashkenazy, 1982 started at around 60 bpm (1 beat = quarter note) while Nikolai Lugansky, 2016 at 55 bpm and Mikhail Pletnev, 1987 at 65 bpm.  They are both quite free with the tempo, as called by the fantasy-like character of the piece.
Indeed, the piece feels like 4/4 instead of cut-time, so I don't understand why the edition you cited have it as 2/2.  Furthermore, I have not been able to find any performance where the beginning section is more than 65 bpm even though it is in the Andante range.  Maybe they interpret "Moderato" to means moderate (not too fast, not to slow), and despite it's played in 60 bpm. I can sense that at 60bpm the pace feels "moderate" maybe because there are a lot of arpeggiated 16th notes (4 per beat) which creates a sense of forward movement.  But in the ff section, page 3 in the 1970 edition, all 3 performers played that section faster: Ashkenazy around 75 bpm, Lugansy around 92 bpm, and Pletnev around 98 bpm.  At least this section is a lot closer to the typical Moderato range.
So I would recommend you play the slow section around 60 bpm in 4/4 time (one beat per quarter note).  It is definitely doable and your instinct of what's good is validated by recordings.  However, on the ff section, pick a faster tempo up to the bpm that you can manage for the performance to sound effortless so that you can focus in communicating the (agitated?) impression that Rachmaninoff wanted to create.  For tips on practicing difficult passages, there are several vlog, such as this one by Stanley Do.

I think they're all taking it much too slow.

@phoog First, to get us to a reasonable range let's agree that the beat is a quarter note.  Second, maybe it's the idea that moderato HAS to be 108-120 bpm that's at issue, and has to be moderated (pun intended, or not, your call) by the predominant # of notes per beat, in this case it's 4 sixteenth note / beat?  I call to the witness stand Beethoven Sonata No. 31 1st mov.  (Moderato cantabile molto espressivo) which also has a predominant 4 sixteenth notes / beat.  Ashkenazy in 1972 (wow looks really young) performed it 64 bpm on average!

@phoog I checked out Rachmaninoff playing his own Piano concerto No. 2, score here.    He played around 84 bpm in the beginning main theme (where the piano plays arpeggios, eight 8th note per beat, 1 beat=half-note).  So maybe the highest tempo I would play this G minor etude to be faithful to Rachmaninoff's sense of moderato would be 84 bpm (1 beat=quarter note); still below 108-120, but somewhat comparable because of the # of notes per beat.

@phoog But then, I just noticed that the score I linked above has the MM as half-note = 66 (!), so not only he played a lot faster than his own score, maybe 66 bpm is the correct tempo (close to the recordings), increasing it to 84 bpm if we want, assuming we agree that for the Etude 1 beat = quarter note.  Boosey & Hawkes edition also has the same MM number, has does the Muzgiz1948 edition.

@phoog As for Rachmaninoff playing his own Prelude in F Op. 32 No. 7, the main pulse per half note beat is around 55 (score here, PDF page 29).  But notice the main division is eighth note (4 notes per beat).  So with predominant 4 sixteenth note per quarter-note-beat in the Etude, it's reasonable to play it 55-65 bpm like in the recordings.

Although instructions like moderato or allegro often can be associated with ranges of BPM, those associations are somewhat misleading. In the case of this piece, moderato should be seen as a felt tempo rather than BPM.
Using a metronomic translation of moderato gives, as stated, a tempo of, say, 120 half-notes per minute, which is obviously too fast. Instead, choose a tempo that "feels" moderate. Since 60 BPM (i.e., half-notes per minute) feels good, go ahead with that tempo.
Also, I recommend listening to a variety of recordings and see what range of tempos there are. If there's a particularly appealing recording, use that tempo.
BTW, this piece is most often numbered 8 rather than 5. The ordering changes with different publications. Also, the tempi I've heard are not what I would have thought moderato; they sound slower than that to me.

Again, yes, listen to recordings... In particular, also, note that whatever tempo is chosen, the pros will not sound rushed... which would be antithetical to that "cantabile" indication. So, surely, however fast you decide to play it, you'd want it to sound like you're in control, not rushing. :)

Rachmaninoff didn't record this piece, but he did record his second piano concerto, the first movement of which is also alla breve with a tempo indication of moderato.  He begins the movement at 66 (half note) beats per minute.  If this relates to the range 108-120, it's the 132 quarter notes per minute beings somewhat above it rather than the 66 half notes per minute being significantly below it.
This tells you a few things:

the matching of words and numbers on a metronome scale is approximate -- a rough guideline at best.  It's not necessarily wrong to play somewhat faster or slower.  Even composers who put actual numerical metronome indications are typically on the record as saying that they are not to be observed strictly.

the identity of the metrical unit that corresponds with the metronome/tempo marking isn't strictly determined by the time signature -- at least not in Rachmaninoff's mind.


If I were working on this piece, I'd probably start with the goal of playing 66 half notes per minute and then -- as always -- adjust from there depending on what the piece tells me to do.

Thanks for advice, but I feel that 132 quarter notes per minute is extremely fast for this piece. According to the answer of @GratefulDisciple 60 quarter notes per minute is more in accordance with recordings of this piece. I also feel that 60 quarter notes per minute sounds good here

@HåkonHægland great!  As I said, do what the piece tells you.  At least now you know that Rachmaninoff didn't mean 108 to 120 half notes per minute.  It's ever so probable that he himself played it slower than the concerto; the musical material is of a distinctly different character.  I just picked 66 as a suggested starting point because it was the one data point uncovered by my five-minute search.

@HåkonHægland the more I look at this, though, the more I think that the world is playing this piece at half tempo.  Another piece in cut time marked moderato that Rachmaninoff recorded is the F major prelude op. 32 no. 7, and that is also at around 120 quarters per minute.  I think those 16th notes are supposed to be light arpeggiated texture, not lugubrious as most people play them.  This reminds me of the moonlight sonata, especially Benjamin Zander's take on it: https://music.stackexchange.com/a/112160/2257
